# Printing a sub-array with built-in functions without using extra memory

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I've an array:

```java
int[] array = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

I want to print a **sub-array** of the above array starting from index `i` and ending at index `j`. For example, if *i=3* & *j=6*, the sub-array to be printed would be:
`[3, 4, 5, 6]` or simply as `3 4 5 6`

We can simply print the sub-array with a for loop as:

```java
for (int k=i; k<=j; k++) System.out.print(array[k]+" ");
```

But I'm looking for a method to achieve this like Arrays `toString()` method.
So, we can use **Arrays.copyOfRange()** to create a copy of the desired sub-array and print it as:

```java
int[] subArray1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, i, j+1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray1));
```

There are few other ways to achieve this as well but all of them tend to use extra space to create a copy of the sub-array. Is there any method or way (except the above) to directly print the sub-arrays from the given indices without using extra memory?

Comment: Any method you would find would probably do it using one of the methods you stated and would have the same limitations.  I might consider using a List and using the `subList` feature.

Comment: you can just copy the source code of `Arrays.toString` and introduce start and end indices as parameters. Or what else is so special about `Arrays.toString`?

Comment: `Arrays.toString()` just uses a `StringBuilder` internally and a for-loop which adds each element to the builder and then returns the string with `toString()` when done.

Comment: @f1sh I never mentioned that I want a method exactly the same as `Arrays.toString()`, any method that can achieve the above is fine for me.

Comment: Method `Arrays.toString` also uses extra memory: a string builder to append the contents of the _entire_ input array and then creating a string.  If you need just to print the contents of the array between the two indexes, you should create your own utility class using `for` loop or streams.

Comment: do check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array